# How to find all elements in a numpy 2-dimensional array that match a certain list?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2-dimensional NumPy array, for example:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]])
```

I would like to get all elements from that array which are in a certain list, for example (1, 3, 4). The desired result in the example case would be:

```
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]])
```

I know that I can just do (as recommended here [Numpy: find elements within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-elements-within-range)):

```
np.logical_or(
    np.logical_or(cc_labeled == 1, cc_labeled == 3),
    cc_labeled == 4
)
```

, but this will be only reasonably effective in the example case. In reality iteratively using for loop and numpy.logical_or turned out to be really slow since the list of possible values is in thousands (and numpy array has approximately the dimension of 1000 x 1000).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.in1d`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) -

```
A*np.in1d(A,[1,3,4]).reshape(A.shape)
```

Also, [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) could be used -

```
np.where(np.in1d(A,[1,3,4]).reshape(A.shape),A,0)
```

You can also use [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) to find such matches by using its optional `'side'` argument with inputs as `left` and `right` and noting that for the matches, the searchsorted would output different results with these two inputs. Thus, an equivalent of `np.in1d(A,[1,3,4])` would be -

```
M = np.searchsorted([1,3,4],A.ravel(),'left') != \
    np.searchsorted([1,3,4],A.ravel(),'right')
```

Thus, the final output would be -

```
out = A*M.reshape(A.shape)
```

Please note that if the input search list is not sorted, you need to use the optional argument`sorter` with its `argsort` indices in `np.searchsorted`.

Sample run -

```
In [321]: A
Out[321]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 0, 2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]])

In [322]: A*np.in1d(A,[1,3,4]).reshape(A.shape)
Out[322]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]])

In [323]: np.where(np.in1d(A,[1,3,4]).reshape(A.shape),A,0)
Out[323]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]])

In [324]: M = np.searchsorted([1,3,4],A.ravel(),'left') != \
     ...:     np.searchsorted([1,3,4],A.ravel(),'right')
     ...: A*M.reshape(A.shape)
     ...: 
Out[324]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4],
       [3, 3, 0, 4, 4]])
```

Runtime tests and verify outputs -

```
In [309]: # Inputs
     ...: A = np.random.randint(0,1000,(400,500))
     ...: lst = np.sort(np.random.randint(0,1000,(100))).tolist()
     ...: 
     ...: def func1(A,lst):                         
     ...:   return A*np.in1d(A,lst).reshape(A.shape)
     ...: 
     ...: def func2(A,lst):                         
     ...:   return np.where(np.in1d(A,lst).reshape(A.shape),A,0)
     ...: 
     ...: def func3(A,lst):                         
     ...:   mask = np.searchsorted(lst,A.ravel(),'left') != \
     ...:          np.searchsorted(lst,A.ravel(),'right')
     ...:   return A*mask.reshape(A.shape)
     ...: 

In [310]: np.allclose(func1(A,lst),func2(A,lst))
Out[310]: True

In [311]: np.allclose(func1(A,lst),func3(A,lst))
Out[311]: True

In [312]: %timeit func1(A,lst)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.9 ms per loop

In [313]: %timeit func2(A,lst)
10 loops, best of 3: 30.9 ms per loop

In [314]: %timeit func3(A,lst)
10 loops, best of 3: 28.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: I went with the np.where(...) variant, because it is the most intuitive to understand. Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

Use [`np.in1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html):

```
np.in1d(arr, [1,3,4]).reshape(arr.shape)
```

`in1d`, as the name suggest, operates on the flattened array, therefor you need to reshape after the operation.