# Python find index of items in list b from list a

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, list, numpy

I have two lists such as:

```
aa=[int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]
bb=[int(1000*random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]
```

and i would another list that tells me where in list bb is the item aa; if it doesn't exist then I would like it to return -1.

The lists are likely to be massive and this will have to be run thousands of times so even a time speed up will be massive.

So far the fastest I can find is this:

```
def index_withoutexception(aa,bb):
    try:
        return aa.index(bb)
    except:
        return -1
ls = [index_withoutexception(bb,i) for i in aa]
```

is there a quicker way to achieve this?

n.b. problem with if statements is that i can't find a function that returns a nan/-1 they all throw exceptions and this is the slow bit...i gather

Comment: using a dictionary instead of a list?  Then lookups would be `O(1)` time instead of `O(n)` time.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your approach in terms of speed and being pythonic.

Comment: What if the item in aa is listed twice in bb ?? `index()` would only return the first occurance. How would you like to handle that ?

Comment: I can confirm that the lists will be unique, I am just using a random number array for the sake of the question. To make it easier in this example then for multiple entries the first entry is fine.

Answer (score 2):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package can be used to solve this problem in a fully vectorized manner (disclaimer: I am its author). Note that you would do well to replace the rest of your code with numpy as well, since otherwise that is bound to become the bottleneck.

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
i = npi.indices(aa, bb, missing='mask').filled(-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach based on [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) and inspired by [`this other post`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945323/3293881) -

```
sidx = np.argsort(bb)
L = np.searchsorted(bb,aa,sorter=sidx,side='left')
R = np.searchsorted(bb,aa,sorter=sidx,side='right')
out = np.where(L != R,sidx[L],-1)
```

Please note that if `bb` is already sorted, you can skip the calculation of `sidx` and all other parts with `sidx` could be removed, thereby boosting the performance. The shortened code for such a case would be -

```
L = np.searchsorted(bb,aa,side='left')
R = np.searchsorted(bb,aa,side='right')
out = np.where(L != R,L,-1)
```

Also note that the output would be a NumPy array. If absolutely needed as list output, you can do `out.tolist()`.

### Runtime test

Let's time the proposed approach against the original loopy version.

1] Setup inputs :

```
In [171]: import numpy as np
     ...: 
     ...: # Create random unique lists
     ...: 
     ...: # 1. Random elements
     ...: aa=[int(1000*np.random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]
     ...: bb=[int(1000*np.random.random()) for i in xrange(10000)]
     ...: 
     ...: # 2. Unique elements
     ...: aa = np.unique(aa)
     ...: bb = np.unique(bb)
     ...: 
     ...: # 3. Since np.unique sorts the elements, let's randomize them
     ...: aa = aa[np.random.permutation(aa.size)]
     ...: bb = bb[np.random.permutation(bb.size)]
     ...: 
     ...: #4. Finall make lists from the arrays
     ...: aa = aa.tolist()
     ...: bb = bb.tolist()
     ...:
```

2] Define the loopy and vectorized versions :

```
In [172]: def index_withoutexception(aa,bb):
     ...:     try:
     ...:         return aa.index(bb)
     ...:     except:
     ...:         return -1
     ...:     

In [173]: def vectorized_approach(aa,bb):
     ...:     sidx = np.argsort(bb)
     ...:     L = np.searchsorted(bb,aa,sorter=sidx,side='left')
     ...:     R = np.searchsorted(bb,aa,sorter=sidx,side='right')
     ...:     return np.where(L != R,sidx[L],-1)
     ...:
```

3] Finally verify and time the results :

```
In [174]: out1 = [index_withoutexception(bb,i) for i in aa]

In [175]: out2 = vectorized_approach(aa,bb)

In [176]: np.allclose(out1,out2)
Out[176]: True

In [177]: %timeit [index_withoutexception(bb,i) for i in aa]
100 loops, best of 3: 11.6 ms per loop

In [178]: %timeit vectorized_approach(aa,bb)
1000 loops, best of 3: 780 µs per loop
```

Comment: While this is very fast, it is sorting the lists and I need to keep the lists in the original order and get their indexes based on that.

Comment: @bpython If you are talking about the first version with `sidx = np.argsort(bb)`, it uses those `argsort-ed indices` to get their indices based on the original order. It confirms that in the verify results section, where we are doing `np.allclose(out1,out2)` that puts out `True` indicating the results match between the vectorized and original version. Or did I misunderstand something here?

Comment: sorry for the ambiguity but I cannot re-order the lists, when posting the question I forgot that np.unique gave an ordered list. the lists i am using this on are in a special order and that needs to be maintained; hence I am using a for loop and catching the exceptions in my example

Comment: @bpython That would be a problem then. Could you convert it to a regular ordered list or better a NumPy array and then use this approach?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `dict`, or `defaultdict(list)`, mapping each element to the index (or indices) it appears at. This way, you need some more space (somewhat more than the original list, but still in the same ballpark), but once the dict is created, each index lookup will be O(1).

```
>>> lst = [random.randint(0, 100) for _ in range(100)]
>>> indices = collections.defaultdict(list)
>>> for i, e in enumerate(lst):
...     indices[e].append(i)
...
>>> indices[30]
[21, 28, 89]
```

Applied to your specific problem, you could try something like this:

```
>>> aa = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(20)] # [3, 9, 4, 5, 6, 5, 2, 4, 7, 4, 4, 9, 10, 8, 8, 7, 6, 3, 3, 3]
>>> bb = [random.randint(0, 10) for _ in range(20)] # [10, 7, 4, 9, 8, 4, 10, 7, 9, 1, 4, 8, 8, 3, 8, 0, 1, 10, 1, 6]
>>> aa_indices = {e: i for (i, e) in reversed(list(enumerate(aa)))} # {2: 6, 3: 0, 4: 2, 5: 3, 6: 4, 7: 8, 8: 13, 9: 1, 10: 12}
>>> b_in_a = [aa_indices.get(b, -1) for b in bb]
>>> b_in_a
[12, 8, 2, 1, 13, 2, 12, 8, 1, -1, 2, 13, 13, 0, 13, -1, -1, 12, -1, 4]
```

Note: This is using `reversed` because otherwise the dictionary would contain the *last* index of the given element.

Some timing analysis using IPython's `%timeit`: This approach takes only 2.24 ms for creating the dict and another 2.88 ms for the final list, as opposed to 173 ms for your original approach.

```
>>> %timeit [index_withoutexception(bb,i) for i in aa]
10 loops, best of 3: 173 ms per loop
>>> %timeit bb_indices = {e: i for (i, e) in reversed(list(enumerate(bb)))}
100 loops, best of 3: 2.24 ms per loop
>>> %timeit [bb_indices.get(i, -1) for i in aa]
100 loops, best of 3: 2.88 ms per loop
```