# Sort rows array to match order of another array using first column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays of data, array A has 4 columns and about 59,000 rows, array B has 24 columns and about 45,000 rows. Array A's first 3 columns has the same data as array B's first 3 but in a different order. I want to reorder each row of array A by array B using the first column. I am finding answers but only for arrays that are the same length. I can't find any answer for arrays that aren't the same length.

I did find one answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37856463/sort-rows-of-array-to-match-order-of-another-array-using-an-identifier-column) but I kept getting an error: "Too many indices for array". That error would occur on the first line of the answer `sidx = A[:,0].argsort()` I'm not sure how I would go about fixing that.

I'm not sure if this is helpful or not but the first column of both arrays are integers. Everything else are floats. If there is some solution to that error or another type of solution to the problem I'm having, any help would be much appreciated!

Here is how both arrays look too.

```
In: arrayA
Out: array([(8846,  73.00, 57.56, 1.),
   (4814, 347.21, 56.61, 0.),
   (2779,  72.14 , 57.34, 0.),
   (1439,  30.24, 64.81, 1.),
   (3677,  85.50, 31.85, 1.),
   (9777, 199.95, 50.46, 1.)])
In: arrayB
Out: array([(2779,  72.14 , 57.34, 17.165, 0.005, 1.329, 19.745, 0.031),
   (9777, 199.95, 50.46, 15.19, 0.002, 0.019, 19.193, 0.023),
   (8846, 73.00, 57.56, 14.21, 0.002, 1.754, 16.918, 0.007),
   (3677, 85.50, 31.85, 20.1, 0.073, 2.394, 23.976, 1.091, 4.441)])
```

I want the end product to be a sorted version of array A so that each index of A matches each index of array B

```
In: arrayA_sorted
Out: array([(2779,  72.14 , 57.34, 0.),
   (9777, 199.95, 50.46, 1.),
   (8846, 73.00, 57.56, 1.),
   (3677,  85.50, 31.85, 1.),
   (4814, 347.21, 56.61, 0.),
   (1439,  30.24, 64.81, 1.)])
```

Here, the first three columns of indices 0 to 3 of arrayA_sorted matches the first three columns of array B. The extra two rows isn't touched because they can't be matched to anything and is left at the bottom of the array.

Comment: How can the two columns (first one of array A and B) have the same data if they have different length?

Comment: Maybe, could you provide a simplified example to understand what you want to do? For example, using only two arrays of 10 and 7 elements each, showing the desired output

Comment: @Daniele sorry for the confusion. The first three columns does have the same data as each other but one has more data than the other. Like having an array that goes 1 through 5 then another array that has 1 through 10. The first array (of 1 through 5) has the same data that's in the other array.