# Numpy int array: Find indices of multiple target ints

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a large numpy array (`dtype=int`) and a set of numbers which I'd like to find in that array, e.g.,

```
import numpy as np
values = np.array([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 1])
searchvals = [3, 1]
# result = [0, 2, 3, 8, 10]
```

The `result` array doesn't have to be sorted.

Speed is an issue, and since both `values` and `searchvals` can be large,

```
for searchval in searchvals:
    np.where(values == searchval)[0]
```

doesn't cut it.

Any hints?

Comment: What must be the output array format? Owing to different output lengths at each iteration, it can't be stored in a regular shaped array IIUC. Or could we conglomerate all in one 1D array?

Comment: Ideally, I'll end up with an array of indices (like `result` in the example).

Comment: Ah lovely! Didn't notice that.

Comment: `np.in1d(values, searchvals)` possibly? And of course `values[np.in1d(values, searchvals)]` if you want to see the actual numbers..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this fast enough?

```
>>> np.where(np.in1d(values, searchvals))
(array([ 0,  2,  3,  8, 10]),)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say [using `np.in1d`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38266343/3293881) would be the intuitive solution to solve such a case. Having said that, based on [`this solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34945323/3293881) here's an alternative with [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html)  -

```
sidx = np.argsort(searchvals)
left_idx = np.searchsorted(searchvals,values,sorter=sidx,side='left')
right_idx = np.searchsorted(searchvals,values,sorter=sidx,side='right')
out = np.where(left_idx != right_idx)[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you avoid numpy all together?  List concatenation should be much faster than relying on numpy's methods.  This will still work even if `values` needs to be a numpy array.

```
result = []
for sv in searchvals:
    result += [i for i in range(len(values)) if values[i] == sv]
```