# Numpy matrix comparison to several criteria

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, string-comparison

I'm working on comparing values in a numpy matrix.

Initially I wanted to check if any of the values in the matrix m were smaller than X, so I used:

```
(m<(X)).any()
```

Which worked fine, but now I would like it to ignore all 0 values in the matrix, so in essence to tell me if any values in the matrix m are in that range 0 < m < X.

I've figured a way to do this by going into a while look put was hoping that there might be a similar function to that above that could do the trick?

Many Thanks

Comment: you can do `(m > 0 ) & (m < X)`

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-elements-within-range

Comment: Not a very apparent dupe, since that was all 1d.

Answer (score 1):

Much like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-elements-within-range), you can do

```
np.where(np.logical_and(0<a,a<6))
```

And it will give you two arrays, which tell you the locations in your matrix.

```
(array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1], dtype=int32),
 array([1, 2, 0, 1, 2], dtype=int32))
```

Unlike the above, you have an n-dimensional array, and the output of that may not be as useful as using a [masked array](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.html)

```
b=np.ma.masked_where(np.logical_or(a<=0,a>=6),a)

b
Out[40]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [-- -- --]],
             mask =
 [[ True False False]
 [False False False]
 [ True  True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Since that can give you a more useful array that preserves location.