# How to check efficiently numpy array contains item within given range?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array, called `a` , I want to check whether it contains an item in a range, specified by two values.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(100)

mintrshold=33
maxtreshold=66
```

My solution:

```
goodItems = np.zeros_like(a)
goodItems[(a<maxtreshold) & (a>mintrshold)] = 1

if goodItems.any(): 
   print (there s an item within range)
```

Can you suggest me a more effective, pythonic way?

Comment: I don't know about numpy per se, but with normal python list I'd write it like; if any(mintrshold < x <= maxtreshold for x in a): print('True')

Comment: Since you are interested in finding if any item exists: as a general recommendation, use a generator expression with `any` if you expect to find a valid item early in the array - being able to return `True` without iterating through the whole array can save a lot of runtime. Use a numpy expression with `.any()` if you don't expect an item early or at all. Always benchmark with real data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy: find index of the elements within range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-index-of-the-elements-within-range)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Numpy arrays doesn't work well with pythonic `a < x < b`. But there's func for this:

```
np.logical_and(a > mintrshold, a < maxtreshold)
```

or

```
np.logical_and(a > mintrshold, a < maxtreshold).any()
```

in your particular case. Basically, you should combine two element-wise ops. Look for [logic funcs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.logic.html#logical-operations) for more details

Comment: Thank you, it is more elegant and 2.5 times faster than my naive solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to the pure Numpy answer we can also use `itertools`

```
import itertools

bool(list(itertools.ifilter(lambda x: 33 <= x <= 66, a)))
```

For smaller arrays this would suffice:

```
bool(filter(lambda x: 33 <= x <= 66, a))
```

Comment: I tried your second line, but it does not work, always ends up being True

Comment: I thought that was the desired output, to return `True` if numbers in the array do fall within the condition. If you need list/array of bools returned let me know and I can modify it for that.

Comment: You interpreted my question well,but if a=np.arange(100,120), your second line still returns True

Comment: It returns `False` for me, I think maybe you are copying or typing something incorrectly. Both of my one-liners return `False` given that `a=np.arange(100,120)`

Comment: I tried your second oneliner with pyton 3.6, it returns True, in python 2.5 it returns False (a=np.arange(100,120)):D. I only checked it with 3.6 only yesterday.

Comment: well I am in Python 2.7 so that is what I gave the answer for. you never specified whether this was specific to 2 or 3

Comment: Well it was not specific :D