# How can I find the specific interval (via list) within which a given value occurs, in order to return the corresponding value from a second list?

Tags: python-3.x, loops, numpy, count, histogram

I am writing a python code to act as a gradebook. I have calculated the total number of points earned by each student and am now stuck on the last step of my code - assigning a letter grade to a student. The structure of my code is to define functions that evaluate a single student's performance, so that one "master function" can repeatedly call the functions by an index number corresponding to each student. As such, I was able to produce a working code that I am trying to condense and simplify. I've checked out similar questions in [posts like these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-elements-within-range), but I haven't been able to adapt these approaches to my problem (I think because my for-loop screws up the indexing).

**Working code:**

```
import numpy as np

failing_score = 100
perfect_score = 200
letter_grades = ['A', 'A-', 'B+', 'B', 'B-', 'C+', 'C', 'C-', 'D+', 'D', 'D-', 'F']
grade_borders = np.linspace(perfect_score, failing_score, len(letter_grades))

print(grade_borders)
>> [ 200.          190.90909091  181.81818182  172.72727273  163.63636364
  154.54545455  145.45454545  136.36363636  127.27272727  118.18181818
  109.09090909  100.        ]

def get_letter_grade(student_grade, grade_borders=grade_borders):
    """
    perfect score = 200, failing score ≤ 100

    190.9 - 200:    A
    181.8 - 190.9:  A-
    172.7 - 181.8:  B+
    etc
    """
    if student_grade >= grade_borders[1]:
        letter = 'A'
    elif grade_borders[2] <= student_grade < grade_borders[1]:
        letter = 'A-'
    elif grade_borders[3] <= student_grade < grade_borders[2]:
        letter = 'B+'
    elif grade_borders[4] <= student_grade < grade_borders[3]:
        letter = 'B'
    elif grade_borders[5] <= student_grade < grade_borders[4]:
        letter = 'B-'
    elif grade_borders[6] <= student_grade < grade_borders[5]:
        letter = 'C+'
    elif grade_borders[7] <= student_grade < grade_borders[6]:
        letter = 'C'
    elif grade_borders[8] <= student_grade < grade_borders[7]:
        letter = 'C-'
    elif grade_borders[9] <= student_grade < grade_borders[8]:
        letter = 'D+'
    elif grade_borders[10] <= student_grade < grade_borders[9]:
        letter = 'D'
    elif grade_borders[11] <= student_grade < grade_borders[10]:
        letter = 'D-'
    elif student_grade < grade_borders[11]:
        letter = 'F'
    return letter

print(get_letter_grade(182)) 
>> A-
```

I don't like having to specify each index and each letter grade using so many if/elif loops. So I tried to modify my approach by using a for-loop; the values at the boundaries (A and F) are handled separately while the grades in-between can be handled by the same code as functions of index.

**Unsuccessful attempt:**

```
def assign_letter_grade(student_score, grade_borders=grade_borders, letter_grades=letter_grades):
    """
    This is my unsuccessful attempt at replicating the function above.
    """
    res = 0 # not including this line ==> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'res' referenced before assignment
    for idx in range(len(grade_borders)):
        if idx == 0:
            if student_score >= grade_borders[1]:
                res = letter_grades[idx]
                print("--", res)
        elif idx > 0 and idx < len(letter_grades)-1:
            if (student_score >= grade_borders[idx+1]) and (student_score < grade_borders[idx]) is True:
                res = letter_grades[idx]
                print("--", res)
        elif idx == len(letter_grades)-1:
            if student_score < grade_borders[len(grade_borders)-1]:
                res = letter_grades[idx]
                print("--", res)
    return res

print(assign_letter_grade(182))
```

**Question:**
What is my mistake in the code just above? Is this a dumb approach (and why /why not?) I've thought about another alternate method that uses a histogram to find the non-zero interval corresponding to a student's grade, but I'm not sure about the efficiency and implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For interval search, you can use numpy's [searchsorted](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html). Things will be more smooth if you sort the values from smallest the largest though.

```
letter_grades = np.array(letter_grades[::-1])
grade_borders = grade_borders[::-1]

def assign_letter_grade(student_score, grade_borders=grade_borders, letter_grades=letter_grades):
    return letter_grades[np.searchsorted(grade_borders, student_score)]
```

A few example on this function:

```
assign_letter_grade(95)
Out: 'F'

assign_letter_grade(105)
Out: 'D-'

assign_letter_grade(182)
Out: 'A-'
```

The same can be done with Python's bisect module.

```
import bisect

bisect.bisect(grade_borders, 182)
Out: 10

letter_grades[bisect.bisect(grade_borders, 182)]
Out: 'A-'
```

The advantage of the numpy function is that it is vectorized so you can pass an array of scores:

```
assign_letter_grade([95, 110, 135, 157, 189, 198])
Out: 
array(['F', 'D', 'C-', 'B-', 'A-', 'A'], 
      dtype='<U2')
```

Of course the same can be done with bisect in a loop but numpy's version will probably be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to adapt the histogram approach, but with a deprecation warning.

```
def hlet(student_score, grade_borders=grade_borders):
    bins = grade_borders[::-1]
    interval, _, _ = plt.hist(student_score, bins=bins)
    interval = interval[::-1]
    letter_idx = np.where(interval>0)[0]
    return letter_grades[letter_idx]

print(hlet(182))

>> VisibleDeprecationWarning: converting an array with ndim > 0 to an index will result in an error in the future
  return letter_grades[letter_idx]
A-
```

While this approach works, I am still curious to see how other approaches attack this problem.