Is there a Numpy function to subset an array based on values (not indices) in a slice or range?
I am trying to extract, from an array, all values within a certain slice (something like a range, but with optional start, stop and step). And in that, I want to benefit from the heavy optimizations that range objects employ for range.__contains__(), which implies they don't ever have to instantiate the full range of values (compare Why is "1000000000000000 in range(1000000000000001)" so fast in Python 3?).
The following code works, but it's horribly inefficient because i is converted to a full-fledged array, increasing memory use and runtime.
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([0, 20, 29999999, 10, 30, 40, 50])
M = np.max(arr)

# slice based on values
s = slice(20, None)
i = range(*s.indices(M + 1))
print(arr[np.isin(arr, i)])  # works, but inefficient!

Output:
[      20 29999999       30       40       50]

Is there a numpy function to improve that directly? Should I use np.vectorize/np.where instead with a callback using the slice (which feels like it could be slow as well, going back from C++ to Python for every single element [or would it not be doing that?])? Should I subtract start from my values, divide by step, and then see if values are >= 0 && < (stop - start) / step? Or am I missing a much better way?

why are you using range instead of np.arange? that's already an order of magnitude gain

@folengateis good idea, that's better. It's still slow. Consider having a 4 GB array and doing np.isin(arr, np.arange(65000)) a few times...

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13869173/numpy-find-index-of-the-elements-within-range

There isn't anything magical about range.  It's just a way of specifying the end points, and holds off on instantiating the values until needed (as in a for loop or list(range...).)  numpy can't use that - it usually needs a concrete array (nothing 'virtual').  isin documents different strategies.  Most generally it sorts a and b together and looks for duplicates.  Or if b is small enough it can test each element of b and logical_and the results.  But in general it's best to take a building block as the answers demonstrate.

With slice(20, None) all you need to test for is np.nonzero(arr>=20).

@hpaulj "There isn't anything magical about range" - well, there is range.__contains__. It's not magical, but it's certainly implemented in C++ and thus avoids roundtrips from C++ to Python.

range in can still only test one value, and isn't any faster than an inequality test like 23 >= range.start.  I imagine it does a variety of tests - is it an integer, size relative to start, stop, modulus w/r to the step.  For testing scalars and elements of a list it is useful, for testing an array, not.

@hpaulj "For testing scalars and elements of a list it is useful, for testing an array, not." I know that. That's why my question is, is there a numpy function that does that? (It seems there is not.)

Whta is the average length of your array

@Onyambu whatever my users load. Can be 4 bytes to 40 gigabytes.

And is the max of the array the stop? or you can choose any stop?

@Onyambu the user can enter a stop, or none, in which the case maximum of the array will implicitly become the stop. Pretty much like slicing based on indices. Note that stop can exceed the maximum, compare np.arange(20)[:9999] which is a valid expression.

Imagine a user is allowed to input everything that you are allowed to input instead of ... in (a 1D) array[...] expression (a simple int, :, 1:, 10:20, ::2,... ), except that the slice/range expression shall be applied to values and not indices.

Apply the answer below but instead return array[mask] instead of np.nonzero(mask)

@jared's answer makes good use of numpy.  numpy uses slices for indexing, but has little use for a 'lazy' range. Widely used arange creates the whole array.  Even index_tricks classes that use slice notation translage that into arange or linspce calls. isin compares whole arrays, not 'lazy' range objects. In many years of following SO [numpy] I have not seen a request like yours.

@hpaulj "In many years of following SO [numpy] I have not seen a request like yours." - this is good, right? Usually, people get called out for asking a duplicate question, not a novel one.

The point I was trying to make is that it's unlikely to find a stock function for a rarely needed task.  My guess is that to do better than jared, you need to use numba (or cython)

Based on this comment, I think you just need to check > and < and return the nonzero indices from that result.
import numpy as np

def get_indices_within_range(arr, start, stop, step=None):
    mask = np.ones_like(arr, dtype=bool)

    if start is None and stop is None:
        raise ValueError("At least one of start and stop must not be None.")
    if start is not None:
        mask *= arr >= start
    if stop is not None:
        mask *= arr < stop
    if step is not None and step != 1:
        if start is not None:
            mask *= (arr - start)%step == 0
        else:
            mask *= arr%step == 0

    if len(arr.shape) > 1:
        return np.nonzero(mask)
    else:
        return np.nonzero(mask)[0]

rng = np.random.default_rng(2)
arr = rng.integers(0, 100, size=(20,))
print(arr)

indices = get_indices_within_range(arr, 20, 70)
print(indices)
indices = get_indices_within_range(arr, 20, None)
print(indices)
indices = get_indices_within_range(arr, None, 70)
print(indices)
indices = get_indices_within_range(arr, 20, 70, 10)
print(indices)
indices = get_indices_within_range(arr, None, 70, 10)
print(indices)

Results:
[83 26 10 29 41 81 45  9 33 60 81 72 99 18 88  5 55 27 20 65]

[ 1  3  4  6  8  9 16 17 18 19]
[ 0  1  3  4  5  6  8  9 10 11 12 14 16 17 18 19]
[ 1  2  3  4  6  7  8  9 13 15 16 17 18 19]
[ 9 18]
[ 2  9 18]


Yes, that works. Disadvantage is that it does not consider step; and even the current solution has to iterate twice over the full array. Some languages have minmax to compute min and max in one iteration, compare https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax. Something like this for range verification would be great in numpy.

How would the step be used? It's not clear to me where that comes in.

Well, my question is about slice and range objects, so maybe see how it works there. https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/stdtypes.html#range and https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#slice

I know how step works for those objects, but how it applies to this problem is unclear.

I want the indices of values in the range. If my range is range(0, 10, 3), I want the indices of the values in {0, 3, 6, 9}.

Does the updated code now do what you want?

yes, it does. It's not what I wanted (I could have written such a code myself), but I will accept the answer until a better one comes up. In the end I think numpy does not have this implemented yet, and I fail to find a more efficient implementation even as a C module extension.

If I understood your problem correctly - you wish to pull all values, including and after 20. In such case you can leverage cumulative sum as in:
>>> arr[(arr==20).cumsum()>0] 
array([      20,       30,       40,       50, 29999999])

booleans sum will return 1/0 so cumsum can't go negative, and once it's positive for once - it means 20 was encountered.
----------------EDIT-------------------------
Generalized solution per comments:

create mask covering starting point:

# any condition same rules as above apply - first encounter of matching condition will populate till the end
mask = (arr>20).cumsum()>0


cut of stop condition (stop condition row included - remove insert and [:-1] if you don't want it included:

stop = np.insert((arr==50).cumsum()>0, 0, False)[:-1]


combine mask:

mask  = mask & ~stop


apply step (same as above - question as of where you apply step - this assumes since first match inside mask):

arr = arr[mask][::step]


I want this to work for all possible ranges (or slices), considering start, stop and step.

Also, not after 20, but greater than or equal to 20. It's really about the value, not the index. Sorry that my input array was sorted.

@bers try now - I generalized the solution (principles remains - hence I would keep the initial answer - I feel your particular question is pretty specific - worth keeping high level answer too)

I think you are misunderstading my question. Please help me reformulating it. What I want from the array is (the indices of) all values that are within a certain range. These values are not necessarily in one consecutive chunk. If my array was np.array([0, 20, 29999999, 10, 30, 40, 50]), then I would want [      20 29999999       30       40       50].

arr[arr>=20]  will do then

As I have written above, "I want this to work for all possible ranges (or slices), considering start, stop and step."

x in range(...) is efficient as it can make assertions about what the values in the range will be. It is basically an implementation of f(x) = mx+c where x ∈ Z and N <= x < M.
Generally, to do this in numpy you'd create a set of masks and then & them together to compute a bit-mask of the array of values you are interested in, and then index your values with this bit-mask. This will result in you computing many redundant values, but this is offset by of the efficiencies that numpy offers. eg. no python object overhead per value and being able to use SIMD instructions.
So you could do something like:
values = np.array([[0, 20, 29999999, 10, 30, 40, 50]])

# these values should produce [10, 30, 50]
start = 10 # excludes 0
stop = 100 # excludes 29999999
step = 20  # excludes 20 and 40 (in combination with start=10)

start_mask = start <= values
stop_mask = values < stop
step_mask = (values - start) % step == 0

final_mask = start_mask & stop_mask & step_mask

result = values[final_mask]

assert result.tolist() == [10, 30, 50]

There are still optimisations to made to above code. One of which is to avoid computing and using the step_mask when step == 1 (as the bit mask produced would be all trues). Others might to get numpy to reuse the bit-mask array produced by the start_mask computation, as opposed to creating a new array for each intermediary result.
